# Navigation Bar Glitches at start of refresh new pages

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, visual-glitch

I'm building a website (http://theastbury.terryslaughter.com).

Whenever you navigate to a new page or refresh the current page, the navigation bar glitches. The logo is larger and the menu appears (even though display: none). Then it resizes and the menu disappears.

I'm not sure if it's because the site is too slow or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that is breaking/glitching?

Comment: Here's the codeshare: https://codeshare.io/a3B8pv


When it glitches, it looks the way it does when the css isn't loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers ready the code from top to bottom. Looking at your code you have built the nav before the call for the css.

Your start building the nav on line 15.

And your first call to an internal CSS thats not for google or external fonts is line 48.

Also your divs for your nav are in your head and not the body if I'm I'm reading everything correctly.

Comment: that fixed it!! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have two navs here:
the one in your head at line 15

Then there is also the call to another nav which I assume is a native Wordpress nav  on line 1016 which starts with <-- site-branding -->